# Get all possible pairs within a cell in df python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df such as :

```
COL1 COL2 COL3
G1   1    ['B_-__Canis_lupus']
G1   2    ['A_-__Felis_cattus','O_+__Felis_cattus','D_-__Felis_sylvestris]
G2   1    ['Q_-__Mus_musculus','S_-__Mus_griseus','P_-__Mus_rattus']
```

and I would like from that to create 1 new column :

**COL4** which is all the pairwise possible combination of **COL3** contain (without against itself) and in a form a list of list within cells

Here I should then get :

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
G1   1    ['B_-__Canis_lupus'] NA 
G1   2    ['A_-__Felis_cattus','O_+__Felis_cattus','D_-__Felis_sylvestris'] [['A_-__Felis_cattus','O_+__Felis_cattus'],['A_-__Felis_cattus','D_-__Felis_sylvestris'];['O_+__Felis_cattus','D_-__Felis_sylvestris']] 
G2   1    ['Q_-__Mus_musculus','S_-__Mus_griseus','P_-__Mus_rattus'] [['Q_-__Mus_musculus','S_-__Mus_griseus'],['Q_-__Mus_musculus','P_-__Mus_rattus'],['S_-__Mus_griseus','P_-__Mus_rattus']]
```

does someone have an idea?

here are the data in dic format :

```
   data= {'COL1': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G2'}, 'COL2': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1}, 'COL3': {0: "['B_-__Canis_lupus']", 1: "['A_-__Felis_cattus','O_+__Felis_cattus','D_-__Felis_sylvestris']", 2: "['Q_-__Mus_musculus','S_-__Mus_griseus','P_-__Mus_rattus']"}}
```

I use :

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_csv("test.tab",sep=";")
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: how do you import the data? As a pandas dataframe? It is very relevant to mention which packages you use (for any further help)

Comment: @HansT I updated the post thank you

Comment: you can probably use `df.apply()`, together with `from itertools import combinations`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations`. The `COL3` column contains list as string which requires `literal_eval` to convert to `list`.

```
from itertools import combinations
from ast import literal_eval

def all_combinations(x):
    return [list(combinations(x, i)) for i in range(1, 3)]

df['COL3'] = df.COL3.map(literal_eval)
df['COL3'] = df.COL3.map(all_combinations)
```

Comment: Thanks but I get a result such as : ```[[([,), (',), (B,), (_,), (-,), (_,), (_,), (C```... for COL3 ... It seems to take every element as i instead of just the  'separated containt'

Comment: Can we create a new COL4 instead of overwritting COL3 ? I mean in COL3 there are the first list then the pairs, I would like to have in COL4 only the pairs and NA values when there is only one element in the list